# How can I connect to a remote InfluxDB

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, influxdb

I can't connect to my remote InfluxDB. I pushed my InfluxDB docker image (the latest one from Docker Hub) to cloud foundry and started the app. If I use the ping command

```
$  curl -sl -I http://address:8086/ping
```

*address is just a placeholder for the real IP

I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1440
```

Do I have to add something to the Docker Image? Does someone know how to connect to it? 
Thank you for your help.

Here are the logs:

```
2020-02-18T13:26:26.43+0100 [API/0] OUT Updated app with guid ff79fa42-b225-4c66-aebc-cfc754c04b0e ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2020-02-18T13:26:26.65+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 8078bac2-fb7e-47f3-a85d-f79d2bd1a115 creating container for instance be12bd72-8e35-452c-49de-e1bf
2020-02-18T13:26:37.65+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 8078bac2-fb7e-47f3-a85d-f79d2bd1a115 successfully created container for instance be12bd72-8e35-452c-49de-e1bf
2020-02-18T13:26:37.77+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2020-02-18T13:26:38.20+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD:IP5p9-dfvfRJG1jZOClwZ_ry5liL1lDE
2020-02-18T13:26:42.82+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT influxdb init process in progress...
2020-02-18T13:26:42.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:42.935499Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0L244kTl000 version=1.7.9 branch=1.7 commit=23bc63d43a8dc05f53afa46e3526ebb5578f3d88
2020-02-18T13:26:42.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:42.935537Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0L244kTl000 version=go1.12.6 maxprocs=8
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041205Z lvl=info msg="Using data dir" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=store path=/var/lib/influxdb/data
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041288Z lvl=info msg="Compaction settings" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=store max_concurrent_compactions=4 throughput_bytes_per_second=50331648 throughput_bytes_per_second_burst=50331648
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041305Z lvl=info msg="Open store (start)" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=store trace_id=0L244ktG000 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=start
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041348Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=store trace_id=0L244ktG000 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=0.045ms
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041387Z lvl=info msg="Opened service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=subscriber
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041400Z lvl=info msg="Starting monitor service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041411Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor name=build
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041421Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor name=runtime
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041430Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor name=network
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041457Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor name=system
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041521Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advance_period=30m
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041545Z lvl=info msg="Starting snapshot service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=snapshot
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041555Z lvl=info msg="Starting continuous query service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=continuous_querier
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041568Z lvl=info msg="Starting HTTP service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=httpd authentication=true
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041574Z lvl=info msg="opened HTTP access log" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=httpd path=stderr
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041584Z lvl=info msg="Auth is enabled but shared-secret is blank. BearerAuthentication is disabled." log_id=0L244kTl000 service=httpd
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041578Z lvl=info msg="Storing statistics" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor db_instance=_internal db_rp=monitor interval=10s
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041628Z lvl=info msg="Listening on HTTP" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=httpd addr=127.0.0.1:8086 https=false
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041648Z lvl=info msg="Starting retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=retention check_interval=30m
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041723Z lvl=info msg="Listening for signals" log_id=0L244kTl000
2020-02-18T13:26:43.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:43.041789Z lvl=info msg="Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com" log_id=0L244kTl000
2020-02-18T13:26:47.87+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:47.870136Z lvl=info msg="Executing query" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=query query="CREATE USER ifadmin WITH PASSWORD [REDACTED] WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"
2020-02-18T13:26:47.95+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2020:12:26:47 +0000] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=&epoch=ns&q=CREATE+USER+%22ifadmin%22+WITH+PASSWORD+%5BREDACTED%5D+WITH+ALL+PRIVILEGES HTTP/1.1" 200 57 "-" "InfluxDBShell/1.7.9" eeae1cbc-5249-11ea-8002-eeee0affece2 80271
2020-02-18T13:26:51.79+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - ifadmin [18/Feb/2020:12:26:51 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "InfluxDBShell/1.7.9" f1052d30-5249-11ea-8003-eeee0affece2 38
2020-02-18T13:26:51.86+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.869567Z lvl=info msg="Executing query" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=query query="CREATE DATABASE jmeter"
2020-02-18T13:26:51.87+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - ifadmin [18/Feb/2020:12:26:51 +0000] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=&epoch=ns&q=CREATE+DATABASE+jmeter HTTP/1.1" 200 57 "-" "InfluxDBShell/1.7.9" f10539f2-5249-11ea-8004-eeee0affece2 81291
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT /init-influxdb.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882254Z lvl=info msg="Signal received, initializing clean shutdown..." log_id=0L244kTl000
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882284Z lvl=info msg="Waiting for clean shutdown..." log_id=0L244kTl000
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882375Z lvl=info msg="Listener closed" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=snapshot
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882395Z lvl=info msg="Shutting down monitor service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882417Z lvl=info msg="Terminating storage of statistics" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=monitor
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882444Z lvl=info msg="Terminating precreation service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=shard-precreation
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882471Z lvl=info msg="Terminating continuous query service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=continuous_querier
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882528Z lvl=info msg="Closing retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=retention
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882580Z lvl=info msg="Closed service" log_id=0L244kTl000 service=subscriber
2020-02-18T13:26:51.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:51.882618Z lvl=info msg="Server shutdown completed" log_id=0L244kTl000
2020-02-18T13:26:55.54+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.545168Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0L245WjG000 version=1.7.9 branch=1.7 commit=23bc63d43a8dc05f53afa46e3526ebb5578f3d88
2020-02-18T13:26:55.54+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.545197Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0L245WjG000 version=go1.12.6 maxprocs=8
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645680Z lvl=info msg="Using data dir" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=store path=/var/lib/influxdb/data
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645721Z lvl=info msg="Compaction settings" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=store max_concurrent_compactions=4 throughput_bytes_per_second=50331648 throughput_bytes_per_second_burst=50331648
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645735Z lvl=info msg="Open store (start)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=store trace_id=0L245X7G001 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=start
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645786Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=store trace_id=0L245X7G001 op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=0.053ms
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645828Z lvl=info msg="Opened service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=subscriber
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645838Z lvl=info msg="Starting monitor service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645843Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor name=build
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645850Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor name=runtime
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645854Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor name=network
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645864Z lvl=info msg="Registered diagnostics client" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor name=system
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645883Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advance_period=30m
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645889Z lvl=info msg="Starting snapshot service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=snapshot
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645895Z lvl=info msg="Starting continuous query service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=continuous_querier
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645910Z lvl=info msg="Starting HTTP service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=httpd authentication=true
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645915Z lvl=info msg="opened HTTP access log" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=httpd path=stderr
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.645919Z lvl=info msg="Auth is enabled but shared-secret is blank. BearerAuthentication is disabled." log_id=0L245WjG000 service=httpd
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.646003Z lvl=info msg="Storing statistics" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=monitor db_instance=_internal db_rp=monitor interval=10s
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.648680Z lvl=info msg="Listening on HTTP" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=httpd addr=0.0.0.0:8086 https=false
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.648714Z lvl=info msg="Starting retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=retention check_interval=30m
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.648790Z lvl=info msg="Listening for signals" log_id=0L245WjG000
2020-02-18T13:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:26:55.648821Z lvl=info msg="Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com" log_id=0L245WjG000
2020-02-18T13:26:56.59+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
2020-02-18T13:28:31.54+0100 [RTR/14] OUT ccp-influxdb-ci.apps.emea.vwapps.io - [2020-02-18T12:28:31.537112792Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 19 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "10.11.8.226:39928" "10.11.34.95:61133" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"a3766d33-48e1-4e26-7f2f-f6125ce7b01f" response_time:0.007266 gorouter_time:0.000114 app_id:"ff79fa42-b225-4c66-aebc-cfc754c04b0e" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"8a8c75b4bb5af422" x_b3_spanid:"8a8c75b4bb5af422" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"8a8c75b4bb5af422-8a8c75b4bb5af422"
2020-02-18T13:28:31.54+0100 [RTR/14] OUT
 2020-02-18T13:28:31.64+0100 [RTR/18] OUT ccp-influxdb-ci.apps.emea.vwapps.io - [2020-02-18T12:28:31.640897474Z] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 0 19 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT

10.0; WOW64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "10.11.8.226:31322" "10.11.34.95:61133" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"0c985087-0372-4a48-46d1-8204e656b395" response_time:0.006984 gorouter_time:0.000086 app_id:"ff79fa42-b225-4c66-aebc-cfc754c04b0e" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"ae3db301fc8f45b5" x_b3_spanid:"ae3db301fc8f45b5" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"ae3db301fc8f45b5-ae3db301fc8f45b5"
2020-02-18T13:28:31.64+0100 [RTR/18] OUT
2020-02-18T13:56:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:56:55.648914Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=retention trace_id=0L25oOO0000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
2020-02-18T13:56:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T12:56:55.648977Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=retention trace_id=0L25oOO0000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.079ms
2020-02-18T14:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T13:26:55.648885Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=retention trace_id=0L27XFd0000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
2020-02-18T14:26:55.64+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ts=2020-02-18T13:26:55.648930Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0L245WjG000 service=retention trace_id=0L27XFd0000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.058ms
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen here? I see a database and an HTTPD server running. Is HTTPD what is supposed to be answering your HTTP "ping" requests in your app? What ports are exposed from your container? Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: Hey Daniel, the Influxdb has a Ping endpoint, and in it´s documentation I should get the following response :                                                                     HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 9c353b0e-aadc-11e8-8023-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: v1.7.0
X-Request-Id: 9c353b0e-aadc-11e8-8023-000000000000
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2018 16:08:32 GMT                                                                                             I use the official dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb?tab=description

Comment: library/influxdb:latest this is the image cloud foundry has

Comment: Sorry, probably doesn't help a lot, but it worked for me. `cf push -o library/influxdb:latest influx-test`, and I was able to `curl -v https://influx-test.cfapps.io/ping` and confirm a `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` response.

Comment: I looked at the Dockerfile you referenced and it seems to be set in a way that is compatible with CF. CF will take the EXPOSE port and route traffic to that. From what I saw, there is only one port exposed (which is good), 8086, and that seems to be the correct port to route traffic to the HTTPD server running in the container.

Comment: Here's what I would suggest: 1.) `cf ssh` into your app, run `curl -v http://localhost:8086/ping`, confirm if that works (it did for me). 2.) `curl -v https://<your-route>/ping`. Replace `<your-route>` with the route name that you have mapped to your app. Please note that the external route will *not* have port 8086 in it.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thank your for helping me. Do I have this problem maybe because I use in a company proxy? I´ve uploaded InfluxDB through a manifest.yml and added there the proxy configuration of the company. What you mean by external route? and how to ssh into my app using cf?

Comment: its good to be aware you're using a proxy here, as that can impact things, but I don't see the typical signs of proxy issues. In your original note, you mentioned using `curl` for `address:8086` but there is no direct IP/port for accessing something on CF. At least not without a TCP route. A normal route is going to be an HTTP route, and it would always go to port 80 or 443, the platform then redirects to the actual port your app is listening on, in this case 8086. You could use a TCP route, but that didn't seem to be necessary for me. Try making sure you curl the route, `cf app` shows routes.

Comment: Hey Daniel, if I `curl -v` the route I get the response "could not resolve host". The route I am sending the curl is listed in `cf a`.

Comment: If I try to ssh into my app I get following response: `Error opening SSH connection: dial tcp: lookup ssh.sys.placeholder.placeholder.io: no such host`

Comment: Hey Daniel, can you show me the logs of your inlfuxdb running on your cf?

Comment: It sounds like you may have DNS or networking issues. The route you map needs to be resolvable for it to work, you can try to confirm with `nslookup <route>` or `dig <route>` to confirm that it can resolve to an IP. The IP it resolves to also needs to be routable for this all to work. If you're on a corp network, you may have to consider an outgoing proxy as well. Also, SSH may be disabled in your environment. I can't provide a lot of detail on this as I don't know your environment. You'd need to talk with your platform operations team to see if SSH is allowed, and to confirm DNS/network route

Comment: Hey Daniel, I know the problem know. The proxy blocks all connection of ports except port 2003 and 334. Do I have to change only the expose port in the dockerfile to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure.